# Why does my fragment is still added to the backstack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

I'm trying to migrate a part of my app to single activity, and I have 2 kind of fragments: those that I want the user to be able to go back to, and those that I are just "temporary" screens that I don't want to user to be able to go back to.

I thought I could use the backstack for that but it doesn't work.

For the first ones I use:

```kotlin
supportFragmentManager.commit {
    replace(binding.fragmentContainer.id, MyFragment(), MyFragment.TAG)
    addToBackStack(MyFragment.TAG)
}
```

And for the second ones ("temporary" screens) I use:

```kotlin
supportFragmentManager.commit {
    replace(binding.fragmentContainer.id, MyFragment())
}
```

When I check `supportFragmentManager.mBackStack` I can see the backstack is setup as intended, but it doesn't seems to matter, when `onBackPressed` is called, the user can go back to fragments that are not on the backstack.

So I tried to override `onBackPressed` like this:

```kotlin
override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 1)
        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
}
```

But it doesn't seems to work either.

EDIT:
To be clear, I have a `FragmentContainerView` named `fragmentContainer` within my Activity and add the very first fragment using the first code sample I provided, then I add a second fragment using second code sample, then a third fragment using the first code sample. My backstack then look like this:

- MyFirstFragment
- MyThirdFragment

"MySecondFragment" wasn't added to the backstack, as intended, it look exactly like I wanted to, but when I do a `popBackstack`, I don't go back to MyFirstFragment but to MySecondFragment, for unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you are replacing a fragment on top of an activity, it clearly means it the activity has only one fragment. So the backstack count ideally should be 0. In that case your checking logic is incorrect. Instead of if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 1), it should be if (supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount > 0)

Hope it works.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. I have edited my question and hope it's more clear like this.

Comment: Okay, so I read the edited part. I think for achieving what you want, your approach should be something like the following : 
 replace MyFirstFragment, add MySecondFragment and then again add MyThirdFragment and if you want to come back to a first or second from third then you can try popbackstack with index value.

Comment: yes I'm at the point where I think I will just make my own backtrack by storing the tags in a List<String> and use popBackstack with the right tags. I was wondering if there is a better way because this seems a bit hacky.